# Ag.vim: Use word under the cursor as *part* of a search pattern?

Tags: search, vim

Using the Ag.vim plugin you can easily search for the word under the cursor by calling `:Ag` without any arguments, but how can I include the word under the cursor as *part* of a search pattern? I'm trying to add a bit to my vimrc to search for method definitions in Ruby files. Something like:

```
autocmd FileType ruby noremap K :Ag! "\bdef <C-R><C-W>\b"<CR>
```

It doesn't recognize the `<C-R><C-W>`. Also, I've tried both `\b` and `\<`, `\>` as word boundaries. Ag uses `\b` outside the context of Vim, but I know it translates `\<` and `\>` to `\b` in some contexts (not sure about this context though).

Comment: Don't use a generic search tool for that, ctags or cscope are far better at that game and very well supported by Vim without adding plugins.

Comment: @romainl Ah, I've been meaning to learn how to use ctags, I guess now's the time :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I usually use one trick, just press `*` on you current word and then use `:AgFromSearch`, you could specify concrete path e.g `:AgFromSearch /any/path/`

If you really want to do word as part of your search pattern, you can use `<cword>` (current word)

```
 nmap  <silent> <D-f> :Ag "def <cword>" /any/path/<CR>
```

Comment: Cool, I was unaware of `<cword>`, and it works here!

Answer (score 2):

```
augroup Ruby

  " clear this augroup's autocmds
  autocmd!

  " use this version:
  autocmd FileType ruby nnoremap <buffer> K :<C-u>execute 'Ag! "\bdef ' . expand('<cword>') . '\b"'<CR>

  " or this one, ^R^W is obtained by pressing <C-v><C-r> then <C-v><C-w>:
  autocmd FileType ruby nnoremap <buffer> K :Ag! "\bdef ^R^W\b"<CR>

augroup END
```

- Use `augroup` and `autocmd!` as above for a cleaner `~/.vimrc`.
- `nnoremap` is better than `noremap` unless you *really* want a single mapping for normal, visual and operator-pending mode (which doesn't really make any sense).
- `<buffer>` is needed to ensure that your mapping is limited to the current buffer.

Comment: Nice, thanks :). I do have this inside an `augroup` with `autocmd!`, but that's a good point about using `<buffer>` too.